# Add a navigation button to map

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

after much time and effort I have managed to create a map with a set location and add a push pin(marker) to the map showing exact location.  Now I want to add a navigation button,  I have five buttons at the top of the screen that allow zoom in and out street view and satillite view.

The final button is for navigation, I plan to use the coordinates I have and send them to the google maps application so the usert can navigate there.

Is it possible to do this and if so how would I go about doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no documented and supported `Intents` for launching navigation, sorry. You can send them to a simple Google Map or Google StreetView via [their documented `Intents`](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is support for launching navigation from an Intent. Simply use this pattern: 
`http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=startPointLatitude,startPointLongitude&daddr=destinationLatitude,destinationLongitude` for a simple navigation without waypoints.

You need to replace the startPointLatitude and startPointLongitude with the latitude and longitude from your startpoint. Same applies for endPointLatitude and endPointLongitude.

Parse the result to an `Uri` and pass it to the `Intent` and call `startActivity()`.